# File upload - returns null

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading a file in my ASP.NET MVC application. In the .ascx file, I have the following:

```
<form action="/Admin/Mail/ABC" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
<div>               
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="UploadList" onclick="Origin.UploadOptOutList();"/>
</div>
```

in the .js file:

```
Origin.UploadList = function () {
    Origin.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Mail/Upload',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success!');
        }
    });               
}
```

and the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    List<string> validIDs, invalidIDs;
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

When invoking the Action from .js, the 'file' is always NULL. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you cannot upload files asynchronously, unless you are using HTML5. If you still need this feature, you might want to try [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

At second, in your current js you are not sending any data with your request (field `data` in `ajax` method options), and that is why you are not receiving anything at server side. Moreover it is impossible to insert a file in this request as I have mentioned before. The most simple solution for you here is to give up with AJAX and let the file be uploaded in usual way:

View:

```
<form action="/Admin/Mail/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
    <div>               
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="UploadList" />
    </div>
</form>
```

No js here, server code is the same.

Comment: OK- the above would post the form to the action "/Admin/Mail/ABC". What if I want to display an error to the user in case the upload failed. I was hoping to do all that using jQuery. How can I achieve that now?

Comment: You have two options: either keep everything synchronous, deal with whatever error occurs at server side and then return corresponding View (say the same View but with the error message), or you can have a look at the jQuery plugin mentioned in the post, and do prety much all you are trying to achieve, but using only jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
            sm.RegisterPostBackControl(btnEditSubmit);
            Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            Page.Form.Attributes.Add("method", "post");
```

Comment: Can you give more details about where that needs to go?